# Liquibase running from Command line

Tags: liquibase

The liquibase command I am using for rollback is

```
liquibase --defaultsFile= "C:/git/liquibaseproject/src/main/resources/liquibase.properties" --changeLogFile="C:/git/liquibaseproject/src/main/resources/db/db.changelog-master.yml" rollback 1.0
```

I am getting an error "**Unexpected error running Liquibase: db/changelog/01-db-changelog.yml does not exist**"

This is because of my db.changelog-master.yml is using relative paths of the changelogs files.

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - include:
      file: db/changelog/01-db-changelog.yml
  - include:
      file: db/changelog/02-db-changelog.yml
```

It is working fine when I am running my springboot project. I am getting an error only when I am trying to rollback via cmd.

I could use **mvn liquibase:rollback -Dliquibase.rollbackTag=1.0** for rollback but I am trying to create a bat file for rollback.

Comment: Did you try to change the directory you are in when you call the command line? The current working directory (the dir you are in) might affect how (resp. from where) the relative paths are resolved...